# Clearing the entire back stack after navigation

Tags: mvvmcross

Is there a way to clear the entire navigation stack (both ViewModels and Views) after navigating to a particular ViewModel? In this instance I need to destroy the navigation stack when the user logs out. As I understand it, `MvxPopToRootPresentationHint` only helps if the `LoginViewModel` is at the root of the navigation stack in the first place.

I should also mention that my stack on Android contains both activities and fragments, and I need to navigate to a fragment ultimately (so using an intent with `CLEAR_TOP` is difficult here):

```
InterstitialContainerViewModel (NoHistory = true on Activity)
InterstitialViewModel
      ↓
LoginContainerViewModel (NoHistory = true on Activity)
LoginViewModel
      ↓
MainContainerViewModel
MainViewModel && MenuViewModel
                       ↓
                   LogoutAsync
                       ↓
Should give me a new instance of LoginContainerViewModel/LoginViewModel 
with no other ViewModels, Activities, or Fragments in the stack
```

Ideally I'd like to do this platform-independently in the shared code, but if achieving this flow requires custom presenter code that's OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be the cleanest possible way to achieve this, but it seems to work:

**1. Create an MvxPresentationHint (in shared code)**:

```
public class LogoutPresentationHint : MvxPresentationHint
{
}
```

**2. Create a custom presenter with an override for `ChangePresentation`**:

```
internal class MyPresenter : MvxAppCompatViewPresenter
{
    public MyPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> androidViewAssemblies)
        : base(androidViewAssemblies)
    {
    }

    public override Task<bool> ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)
    {
        if (hint is LogoutPresentationHint)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity, typeof(LoginContainerActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            ShowIntent(intent, new Bundle());
            CurrentActivity.Finish();
            Show(new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(LoginViewModel)));
        }

        return base.ChangePresentation(hint);
    }
}
```

**3. Use the custom presenter in `Setup.cs`**:

```
protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    => new MyPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
```

**4. Override `OnBackPressed` in `LoginContainerActivity` to minimise the app when the user presses back**:

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    Minimise();
}

private void Minimise()
{
    var minimiseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
    minimiseIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryHome);
    minimiseIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    StartActivity(minimiseIntent);
}
```

**5. Navigate using the new `MvxPresentationHint` in `LogoutAsync`**:

```
private async Task LogoutAsync()
    => await NavigationService.ChangePresentation(new LogoutPresentationHint());
```

This works almost perfectly. The entire back stack is removed and a fresh instance of the login ViewModels and Activities/Fragments are created and presented correctly. The only caveat that I've found is that if the user presses back (which then minimises the app) and then reopens the app from recents, it reopens to the container activity without the fragment. Only the `ActivityLifetimeListener_ActivityChanged` method is raised in the presenter. It may be possible to hook into that method and present the fragment correctly at that point, but I haven't managed to get that right yet.